# Ford Fusion Check Engine Codes

Tags: ford, cel, fusion

On Saturday the check engine light came on.  This is a 2009 Ford Fusion.   My daughter had just gotten gas so I figured it was gas cap related and did not panic.  On Monday we had it checked at a car parts store and the codes were:  B1318    P0841   P0410  and P049   The light had stayed on in spite of gas cap tightening and driving quite a few miles.  Today (Tuesday) the light has gone off.  Is is possible that all those codes were "false" or have cleared on their own?  I have an appointment to get this checked but was wondering what your thoughts would be. This is a "new to us" used car that we bought on Saturday.

Answer (score 2):

B1318 is low battery voltage

P0841 is a code for the transmission fluid pressure sensor (TFP)

P0410 is a code for the secondary air injection system (pump malfunction)

P049 is not a valid code, they are always Ptxxx.  The first digit 't' (type) is always a 0 (generic) or a 1 (OEM specific).  Perhaps you meant P0449 which is EVAP vent valve/solenoid.

NONE of these codes bears any relation to the gas cap, although the '4' series codes are emissions including the evaporative system (gas cap included).  But P0449 is not a small or gross leak.

It sounds like the battery voltage got low, perhaps scrambled the ECU a bit.  The fact that all codes cleared in a few drive cycles is a good indication that they were phantom.

Monitor to see if they come back, but they appear to be random phantoms and not even related to each other - unless the one "real" code was the battery voltage, and the other codes are a result of the ECU fainting for a moment.

Perhaps get the battery load tested to eliminate that possibility.